# ADXL354 Power Sequencing Sources and LDO's

Tags: voltage, power, analog, linear-regulator

The [ADXL354](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adxl354_355.pdf) with Analog Outputs include three power pins: Analog Power Source `V1P8ANA`, Digital Power Source `V1P8DIG` and Logic High Level `VDDIO`, besides the `VSUPPLY` Main Supply Pin.

According the Power Sequencing datasheet feature (p.22), when `VSUPPLY` is tied to ground, the Analog `V1P8ANA` and Digital `V1P8DIG` Power Sources can be supplied externally.

Which is the purpose of this feature in the `ADXL354`?

For which reason should I use that complex Power Sequencing instead of simply plugging in the `VSUPPLY` to 3.3V?

If the maximum level of these pins is 1.98V, which is finally the purpose of them? It cannot be changed into 3.3V either.

Comment: possibly uses the 1.8 V external power supply for low power application

Answer (score 1):

The V1P8DIG and V1P8ANA provide 1.8V to digital and analog sections respectively. They are internal LDO's that drop the main VCC to around 1.8V, which the IC needs to function. If you already have 1.8V then the LDO's don't work, so you'll bypass the LDO's. My guess is the LDO's are provided because most people use 3.3V for Vcc, you would be less likely to use this accelerator in a product if you had to provide your own 1.8V LDO which adds cost and space (especially since most acellerometers go into products that have tight weight/space requirements like cellphones and drones).

> The LDO regulators are operational when VSUPPLY is between 2.25 V and
>   3.6 V. V1P8ANA and V1P8DIG are the regulator outputs in this mode. Alternatively, when tying VSUPPLY to VSS, V1P8ANA and V1P8DIG are supply voltage inputs with a 1.62 V to 1.98 V range.

Source: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adxl354_355.pdf

Comment: Yes i agree, but.. after the shown paragraph, some explanation about timings in the sequence of powering over the device, if one is willing to use an external source for them. My question is why should i need that?